# Javascript adding onclick to a dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm trying to create a script to help sort list items, and in doing so I need to dynamically create buttons to select what tags to look for. The problem I am having is that every button element runs the `checktags()` script with the same parameter, despite using a changing value when creating the element.

One thing I noticed is that when I go into chrome developer tools and look at the buttons, there is no "onclick" attribute despite it still having some functionality.

```
    function checktags(tagnum){
        var res = document.getElementById("itemlist").innerHTML.split(/\n/);
        for (var i in res) {
            var list = document.getElementById(i).getElementsByTagName("input");
            var itemnum = + i + 1;
            var categorynum = + tagnum + 1;
            if(list[tagnum].checked) alert("List item " + itemnum + ", checkbox " + categorynum + " has been selected");
            else alert("List item " + itemnum + ", checkbox " + categorynum + " is UNchecked");

        }
    }


    function myFunction() {
        var res = document.getElementById("itemlist").innerHTML.split(/\n/);
        res = res.filter(function(str) {return /\S/.test(str);}); // remove empty lines
        var taglist = ["Tag 1", "Tag 2", "Tag 3", "Tag 4", "Tag 5"]


        for (var i in taglist){
            var buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
            buttonElement.onclick = function() {checktags(i);};
            var tagnum = + i + 1;
            alert("Creating button " + tagnum);
            buttonElement.innerHTML = taglist[i];
            document.body.appendChild(buttonElement);
        }


        for (var c in res) {
            var newElement = document.createElement('div');
            newElement.id = c; 
            newElement.innerHTML = + c + 1 + ") " + res[c];

            for( var j in taglist){
                newElement.innerHTML += "<input type='checkbox' value='" + taglist[j] + "'>";
            }
            document.body.appendChild(newElement);
        }

    }


</script>
```

```
<div id="itemlist" style="display:none">

    List Item 1
    List item 2

    List item 3
    List item 4
    List item 5

</div>
```

[JS Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/noingwhat/3hsgabw2/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27373951/2025923

Comment: @Tushar, that solved my problem perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Okay, then I can mark the question as dupe.